# Trying to change the element style when clicking on button

Tags: javascript

I have already found a way to get what I want, but I'm trying to understand why the next code doesn't work.

If to be more precise why does the function `showHideTaskDetails()` doesn't seem to do what it should do (BTW leave aside its name, it's not an indication of its purpose)

---

I expect the following to happen:

When clicking on the button with the class "fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-down", the value of the variable `hideContent` change to the opposite of the current value (if it's true to become `false` and vice versa).

After that if the `hideContent` is true the variable `color` will be "background-color: red" so the style of all dives will change to have background with the color red.

But instead, nothing happens!

HTML

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="">

      <label for="task-headline">Task Headline</label>
      <input type="text" id="task-headline">

      <label for="deadline">Task Deadline</label>
      <input type="date" id="deadline">

      <label for="task-details">Task Details</label>
      <textarea name="" id="task-details" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
      <button id="add-task">Add Task</button>
    </form>
    <div class="tasks-area"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```javascript
const headLineEl = document.getElementById("task-headline")
const deadlineEl = document.getElementById("deadline")
const taskDetailsEl = document.getElementById("task-details")
const TasksAreaEl = document.querySelector(".tasks-area")
addTaskBtn = document.getElementById("add-task")
let hideContent = true
let color = ""
showTasks()

addTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const newTask = collectTaskInfo()
  saveToLs(newTask)
  showTasks()
})


//get from the local storage the current tasks
function getLsData() {
  let currentLsContent = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))
  if (currentLsContent === null) {
    currentLsContent = []
  }
  return currentLsContent

}

//show the tasks on the dom 
function showTasks() {
  const array = getLsData()
  let tasksContainer = []
  array.map(task => {

    const readyTask =
      ` 
                <div class="task-container" style=${color}>
                <div class="main-basic-info">
                <p> <span>Task:</span> ${task.headline} </p>
                <div class="left-part"> 
                    <p> <span>Deadline:</span> ${task.deadline} </p>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-down"  onClick="showHideTaskDetails()"></i>
                </div>
                    
                    </div>
                    <p class="details"> <span>Details:</span> ${task.details} </p>
                </div>
                <br>
            `
    tasksContainer.push(readyTask)
  })
  TasksAreaEl.innerHTML = tasksContainer
}


//hide unhide details

function showHideTaskDetails() {

  hideContent = !hideContent
  console.log(hideContent);
  if (hideContent) color = "background-color: red"
  //    const test =  document.getElementsByTagName('div')
  //    test.style = "background-color: red"

}




//collect task information to object
function collectTaskInfo() {
  const obj = {
    headline: headLineEl.value,
    deadline: deadline.value,
    details: taskDetailsEl.value
  }

  return obj
}

//update the current array in local storage with the new task
function addNewTaskToLsArray(newTask) {
  const currentTaskArrayInLs = getLsData()
  currentTaskArrayInLs.push(newTask)
  const updatedTaskArray = currentTaskArrayInLs
  return updatedTaskArray
}

//save data to local storage
function saveToLs(task) {
  const arrayWithTheNewTask = addNewTaskToLsArray(task)
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(arrayWithTheNewTask))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You showHideTasksDetails function is not re-rendering the page by itself.

You can modify it so that the showTasks function is called again when the showHideTaskDetails is called.

```
    function showHideTaskDetails() {
    hideContent = !hideContent;
    console.log(hideContent);
    if (hideContent) {
      color = "'background-color: red'";
    } else {
      color = "";
    }
    //    const test =  document.getElementsByTagName('div')
    //    test.style = "background-color: red"

    showTasks();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed what you have said but it still doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

first it's onclick not onClick
Second initial value of hideContent is set to true and you're changing it to false when you're calling the showHideTaskDetails fn before if statement